# How to edit space size for indentation

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, indentation

I feel comfortable working with 4-space indentation. However, most of my colleagues want 2 spaces. The linter is set up for 2 spaces.

Is there any way to make WebStorm displays 2 spaces the same size as 4 spaces? So when the code on my local machine would display the way I want and the way the others want on other machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Elastic Indents plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14849-elastic-indents) seems to do what you want (I haven't tried it myself).

Comment: This is awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no way to achieve that. Feel free to vote for "Virtual indents" feature on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237957